# Check for dupe value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that adds items to a select list which works fine. However, what I need to do is compare a value that has already been entered so the user cannot enter dupe values. I know how to compare values but cannot get my head round how to check for value already entered.

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on how to do this. Many thanks

js

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    var boxvalue = $("#box_input").val();
    if (boxvalue == '') {
      $("#niinputmessage").fadeIn(3000).html('No blank entries').fadeOut(5000).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'margin-left': '5px',
        'margin-top': '5px'
      });
      return false;
    }
    count = $('#box_ni').children('option').length;
    $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    if (count > 2) {
      $("#counter").html("No more than 3 items per intake. Please remove items from the list.");
      return false;
    } else {
      count++;
      $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    }
    $("#box_ni").append("<option>" + boxvalue + "</option>");
    $("#box_input").val('');
  });
});
```

js remove function

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
    $("#box_ni > option:selected").each(function() {
      $("#box_ni option:selected").remove();
      count--;
    });
    $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + 
      '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + 
      '</span>').css('color:, black');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for `value` can be done with a selector, but from your append script, you are not adding a value, but rather `<option>value</option>` (as opposed to with a value: `<option value='value'>value</value>`).

You can filter the results by checking the `.text()` of each option:

```
if ($("#box_ni option").filter(function (i,e) { 
        return $(e).text() == boxvalue ; 
    }).length > 0)
{
    $("#counter").html("You've already selected that");
}
```

Snippet showing possible checks with value and text:

```js
var newval = "1"
console.log("1", $("#sel option[value='"+newval+"']").length == 1)

var newval = "3"
console.log("3", $("#sel option[value='"+newval+"']").length == 1)

var newtext = "one"
console.log("one", $("#sel option").filter(function (i,e) { return $(e).text() == newtext; }).length == 1)

var newtext = "three"
console.log("three", $("#sel option").filter(function (i,e) { return $(e).text() == newtext; }).length == 1)
```

```html
<select id='sel'>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However it is still adding items to the list. Thanks

Comment: Did you add a `return false;` after the message?

Comment: Yes I did. very weird the way this is working. when i add item then add another with the same value it triggers the message. However, if I remove that item from the list and try to add it again it's not added to the list

Comment: How do you remove them from the list?  Could be you need a better selector?

Comment: I have added remove function to my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
add this in place of $("#box_ni").append....    
var values = document.getElementsByTagName('option');  
var j=0;  
for(i=0; i < values.length; i++){  
  if(boxvalue == values[i].innerHTML){               
   j++;  
     }  
 }
 if(j==0){
 $("#box_ni").append("<option>" + boxvalue + "</option>");  
 }
```

Comment: The code is working but if there is a dupe and it is not entered in the list it is still incrementing the count var. Is there a way so this dosen't happen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try maintaining the list of values in an array and using that to represent the list's entries.

```
$(function() {
  let boxvalues = [];
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    var boxvalue = $("#box_input").val();
    if (boxvalue == '') {
      $("#niinputmessage").fadeIn(3000).html('No blank entries').fadeOut(5000).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'margin-left': '5px',
        'margin-top': '5px'
      });
      return false;
    }
    count = $('#box_ni').children('option').length;
    $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    if (count > 2) {
      $("#counter").html("No more than 3 items per intake. Please remove items from the list.");
      return false;
    } else {
      count++;
      $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    }
    //Checks and adds the entries
    if(boxvalues.indexOf(boxvalue) === -1) {
      boxvalues.push(boxvalue)
      $("#box_ni").append("<option>" + boxvalue + "</option>");      
    }
    $("#box_input").val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, if the message is displayed if there are dupe items it still adds to the count var. i have changed the message alert to: `$("#nidstrmessage").html("You've already selected that");` just so i can keep my counter working. Is there a way that if there are dupes then do not inc the count var. Thanks